# Condition using df index range

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to add region column to `df1` using `ip range` stated in `df2` given two data frames:

- `df1` has `ip_address`
- `df2` has `ip_from`, `ip_to`, `region`

can you make a conditional statement using indexes?
if `df1.ip[0]` is in between specific `ip`, add region in `df1`?
I am guessing there should be a loop in the if statement so that it can loop through `df2` to see where the `ip` ranges are and grab the region.

[image]

I know by adding each condition manually, this will work, 
but is there a way to make condition loop by index?

```
region=[]
for row in df1['ip']:
    if row > 15:
        region.append('D')

    elif row > 10:
        region.append('C')

    elif row > 5:
        region.append('B')

    else:
        region.append('A')

df1['region'] = region
```

To make it iterate through rows, can it be done this way?

```
region = []
# For each row in the column,
for row in df1['ip']:
    if (row >= df2.loc[row,'ip_from']) and (row <= df2.loc[row,'ip_to']):
        region.append(df2.loc[row,'region'])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Can you edit your post with a sample of your input and the expected output ?

Comment: i thought i could do it with if loop with index:
conditions:
if ip[i] is in between ip_from and ip_to then region. but it would have to loop through the whole dataframe to check which range ip[i] is in...

Comment: Please, Edit the question with the code you have already wrote and we will try to improve it. Have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and what makes of a question a good [question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) We will not write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of regions with indices that match ip address value:

```
df1 = {'ip': [13,4,7,2], 'region': []}
df2 = list('AAAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDD')
for i in range(len(df1['ip'])):
    df1['region'].append(df2[df1['ip'][i]])
```